# create a data frame from multiple lists where each items of the list is goes to the columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have lists like this,

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
l2=[2,3,4,5,6]
l3=[3,4,5,6,7]
```

Now I want to create a data frame from those three lists where each items from a list goes into a specific columns, so the data frame would look like,

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
  1      2       3        4      5
  2      3       4        5      6
  3      4       5        6      7
```

I could do this using a for loop and iterating over the values but this will take longer time, so looking for some pandas/python shortcuts to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor with `RangeIndex` converted to strings and added `col`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([l1, l2, l3], columns='col' + pd.RangeIndex(1,len(l1)+1).astype(str))
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     2     3     4     5
1     2     3     4     5     6
2     3     4     5     6     7
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the lists as the values, and form the column names from the length of any list e.g. `l2` using `enumerate`:

```py
pd.DataFrame([l1, l2, l3], columns=[f"col{j}" for j, _ in enumerate(l2, start=1)])
```

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     2     3     4     5
1     2     3     4     5     6
2     3     4     5     6     7
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the multi dimensional array. simple solution

```
    from array import *

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [2,3,4,5,6]
l3 = [3,4,5,6,7]

l4 = [l1,l2,l3]

print("col1 col2 col3 col4 col5")
for i in l4:
    for c in i:
        print(" ",c, end="  ")
    print()
```

and your output is looks like

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
  1    2    3    4    5  
  2    3    4    5    6  
  3    4    5    6    7
```